# eval not working in shellscript

Tags: shell

I am trying to get the value of a variable to be selected by name at runtime, using `eval`, but I don't get its value if `-` (hyphen) is in the name.

```
ENV=dev
REGION=us-east-1

DBUSERNAME=DB_USER_${ENV}_$REGION
DBPASSWORD=DB_PASS_${ENV}_$REGION

eval "USERNAME=\${${DBUSERNAME}}"
eval "PASSWORD=\${${DBPASSWORD}}"

echo USERNAME=$USERNAME
echo PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
```

### RESULT

```
echo USERNAME=east-1
echo PASSWORD=east-1
```

### EXPECTED RESULT

```
echo USERNAME=DB_USER_dev_us-east-1
echo PASSWORD=DB_USER_dev_us-east-1
```

It's working fine if there is no hyphen present in the name.

Comment: Why are you adding additional substitution? `eval "USERNAME=${DBUSERNAME}"` should do the trick

Comment: `DB_USER_dev_us-east-1` conatins value and which I am trying to extract that using `eval` and `$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Investigation

We can see what's happening by running this in shell with `-x` option to trace execution:

```
$ sh -x ./36332134.sh 
+ ENV=dev
+ REGION=us-east-1
+ DBUSERNAME=DB_USER_dev_us-east-1
+ DBPASSWORD=DB_PASS_dev_us-east-1
+ eval USERNAME=${DB_USER_dev_us-east-1}
+ USERNAME=east-1
+ eval PASSWORD=${DB_PASS_dev_us-east-1}
+ PASSWORD=east-1
+ echo USERNAME=east-1
USERNAME=east-1
+ echo PASSWORD=east-1
PASSWORD=east-1
```

Notice that `eval USERNAME=${DB_USER_dev_us-east-1}` gives us `USERNAME=east-1`.  That's parameter expansion in effect, as described in the Bash manual:

> When not performing substring expansion, using the forms documented below (e.g., `:-`), bash tests for a parameter that is unset
>   or null.  Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter
>   that is unset.
>
> **`${parameter:-word}`**
>   Use Default Values.  If `parameter` is unset or null, the expansion of `word` is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of `parameter`
>   is substituted.

Since `$DB_USER_dev_us` is unset, then the expansion of `${DB_USER_dev_us-east-1}` is `east-1`.

### Workarounds

Shell doesn't allow `-` in variable names (including environment variables).  I guess `DB_USER_dev_us-east-1` was set by some non-shell program?  In which case, you'll need a similar non-shell program to retrieve it, I think.  I tested quoting the `-`, but to no avail.

If you can use Bash as your shell, you might want to use an associative array instead of composing variable names.

If you are able to change the environment variables, you might consider changing the `-` to (say) `_`, then using (Bash) `${REGION//-/_}` or (otherwise) `tr` to transform the name:

```
REGION="${REGION//-/_}"            # Bash
REGION="$(echo "$REGION"|tr - _)"  # POSIX
```

Comment: so is there any way that  I can get the expected result, the values with out hypen is working perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

You are evaluating/expanding a few too many times.

Toby's answer is exactly correct (and shows the proper debugging technique for this sort of issue) but the solution to the problem is to unwrap one level of expansion.

You wrote

```
eval "USERNAME=\${${DBUSERNAME}}"
```

which becomes

```
eval "USERNAME=\${DB_USER_dev_us-east-1}"
```

which then gets run through `eval` as

```
USERNAME=${DB_USER_dev_us-east-1}
```

which becomes

```
USERNAME=east-1
```

but you wanted to stop after the first expansion. That is

```
eval "USERNAME=\${DB_USER_dev_us-east-1}"
```

has already performed the expansion you wanted and gotten you the result you needed. So you don't want the `\${...}` bit or `eval`. Just

```
USERNAME=DB_USER_dev_us-east-1
```

which you get from

```
USERNAME=${DBUSERNAME}
```

Unless I've missed something or your example isn't accurate.

Answer (score 0):

As they have explained the problem, here is what you can do

```
$> more a.sh
ENV=dev
REGION=us-east-1

DBUSERNAME=DB_USER_${ENV}_$REGION
DBPASSWORD=DB_PASS_${ENV}_$REGION

eval "USERNAME=${DBUSERNAME}"
eval "PASSWORD=${DBPASSWORD}"

echo USERNAME=$USERNAME
echo PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
```

Results

```
$> ./a.sh
USERNAME=DB_USER_dev_us-east-1
PASSWORD=DB_PASS_dev_us-east-1
```

Comment: In my case " DB_USER_dev_us-east-1 " is holding a value with in , so I am using this eval to print it, echo USERNAME=$USERNAME is just printing the `DB_USER_dev_us-east-1` but not the value which it holds